# build_vignettes() randomly failing

Tags: r, devtools

The following is contained within a vignette file called `test_vignette.Rmd` within the `vignettes` folder of my R library.

````
---
title: "this is a test"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{this is a test}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>"
)
```

Some test text here

```{r}
print("Text code bubble")
```
````

To build the package, I run `devtools::build_vignettes()`

It will sometimes run correctly, but then sometimes it will completely randomly fail:

```
Building my_package vignettes
--- re-building 'test_vignette.Rmd' using rmarkdown
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:\my_files\my_package\vignettes\test_vignette.R': Invalid argument
Quitting from lines 21-22 (test_vignette.Rmd) 
Error: processing vignette 'test_vignette.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
cannot open the connection
--- failed re-building 'test_vignette.Rmd'

SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
  'test_vignette.Rmd'

Error : Vignette re-building failed.
Error: callr subprocess failed: Vignette re-building failed.
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occured
```

I'll try running `build_vignettes()` and it'll work... then not. It happens randomly about 50% of the time.

Lines 21-22 correspond to the little chunk of R code with `print("Text code bubble")`

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue here,
did you recently upgrade R / knitr ? This may have to do with a recent release https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1899 ?

What is the output of: `rmarkdown::render(input = "./vignettes/vignette.Rmd")` ?

Comment: That seems to work fine. Is there a way to use this for `build_vignettes`?